# Math language: there is; for some; and for all

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Let $P$ be a positive $n\times n$ matrix. Given these two definitions:

> Denote by $A(P)$ the set of all nonnegative numbers $\lambda$ for which **there is** a nonnegative vector $x\neq 0$ such that $Px\geq \lambda x$.
>
> Denote by $B(P)$ the set of all nonnegative numbers $\mu$ for which **there is** a nonnegative vector $x\neq 0$ such that $Px\leq \mu x$.

Can I do the following:

**"Fix some nonnegative vector $x\neq 0$, we get $\lambda x\leq Px\leq \mu x$**?"

Does "there is a nonnegative vector" mean inequalities hold **for all** nonnegative vectors?

Comment: Yes because it means "Fix some ARBITARY nonnegative vector ..."

Comment: @Peter: But what is a *nonnegative* vector?

Comment: @Niing I guess a vector with non-negative entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "there is" does not mean "for all".  "There is" means only that you can find one nonnegative vector for which the inequalities hold.

To add a point of clarification:

You can fix a nonnegative $x \ne 0$ *such that* $\lambda x \le Px \le \mu x$, but you cannot fix a nonnegative $x \ne 0$ (with no further assumptions) *and get* $\lambda x \le Px \le \mu x$.

Comment: Then, I guess I cannot fix some nonnegative $x\neq 0$ and get $\lambda x\leq Px\leq \mu x$.

Comment: Right. You can fix a nonnegative $x \ne 0$ *such that* $\lambda x \le Px \le \mu x$, but you cannot fix a nonnegative $x \ne 0$ *and get* $\lambda x \le Px \le \mu x$.